# terminal error: flask run zsh: command not found: flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm using a Mac , the python version is 2.7.10. and I installed flask

```
➜  Flask_blog python Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask
>>>
```

I try to follow the tutorial of flash on http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/

the commands:

```
➜  Flask_blog export FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py
➜  Flask_blog flask run                    
zsh: command not found: flask
➜  Flask_blog
```

code in flaskblog.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

The error is `command not found: flask`

I also tried an other tutorial.

commands:

```
➜  Flask_blog cd /Users/jzd/Movies/flask/Second_video 
➜  Second_video python one.py                           
Sorry
```

code in one.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World'

if __name__ == '__name__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0')
else:
    print("Sorry")
```

the condition `__name__ == '__name__':` did not pass.

I guess the python `venv` matters.

Really want to know how to fix it.

Comment: What is the result of `python -m flask run`? You might want to have a look at [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#what-to-do-if-the-server-does-not-start).

Comment: It works @Andrejs Cainikovs.  You saved me from three day's pending

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try `python -m flask run` instead.

Possible installation issues with `flask` not present, etc, are mentioned in [this section](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#what-to-do-if-the-server-does-not-start) of official Flask documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that the flask path is appended to the $PATH env variable

That might be on the `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file. Edit the file (`nano ~/.zshrc`) and add it there

```
export PATH=$PATH:/flaskpath
```

Then restart the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Verify where you have installed flask:

```
mortiz@florida:~/Documents/projects$ pip freeze |grep -i flask
Flask==1.0.2
mortiz@florida:~/Documents/projects$ pip2 freeze |grep -i flask
Flask==1.0.2
mortiz@florida:~/Documents/projects$ pip3 freeze |grep -i flask
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-CLI==0.4.0
Flask-Jsonpify==1.5.0
Flask-RESTful==0.3.6
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
```

Verify you are installing flask for your correct python version inside your virtual environment.

**Find out your python version "inside your (venv)"**

```
mortiz@florida:~/Documents/projects/python/APIS/new_project_py_2_7$ which python
    /home/mortiz/Documents/projects/python/APIS/new_project_py_2_7/venv/bin/python

(venv) mortiz@florida:~/Documents/projects/python/APIS/new_project_py_2_7$ python --version
Python 3.5.3
```

**Installation of flask for python3**

```
pip3 install flask
#or
python3 -m pip install flask
```

**Installation of flask for python2**

```
pip2 install flask
#or
python2 -m pip install flask
```

**Installation of flask for default python (be careful if you are inside your (venv) or in your shell)**

```
pip install flask
python -m install flask
```

> Explanation

For people who run higher versions of Flask consider evaluating your environment as [explained here](http://migueleonardortiz.com.ar/python/bash-flask-command-not-found-with-flask-1-0-2/1692).

For me the problem was installing flask for python2 when the binary of my (venv) ran python3.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you forget, export `FLASK_APP` you can try this command

```sh
 export FLASK_APP=<your flask file>.py FLASK_ENV=development && flask run
```

you can see in [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/)

Answer (score 1):

When installing flask I saw an error in the end of the installation script saying.

`WARNING: The script flask is installed in '/home/doe/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.`

by doing `echo PATH` I indeed verified that that path was not included in my PATH variable.

I typed `path+=('/home/doe/.local/bin')` and `export PATH`.

Running `echo PATH` again now included the needed path and then `FLASK_APP=my-app.py flask run` worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found that instead of running `python -m flask run` every time, that when I tried to update the Flask package in pip I was told that where I was installing the packages to wasn't on PATH.

I fixed this by running `sudo nano /etc/paths` and adding where my packages were being installed (`/Users/XXXXX/Library/Python/3.9/bin`) to the end of this list and saving it.

This allowed me to run `flask run` instead of `python3 -m flask run`